# How do I make my webview stop certain links from opening on browser

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

```
package net.developerbase.android.app;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String uas = "AppleWebKit/537.36" + "(KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/30.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36";
        final WebView view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        view.getSettings().setBlockNetworkLoads(false);
        view.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
        view.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        view.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        view.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
        view.getSettings().setUserAgentString(uas);
        view.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
        view.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        view.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        view.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        view.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        view.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        view.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        view.loadUrl("http://58.182.126.214:4567");
            }
```

### }

How do i make it so that my app will keep a certain link on the app and other links on browser.

Please help me add your piece of code into my code as i am a noob at android programming still. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

I think you need WebViewClient's function WebViewClient `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("www.example.com")) {
        // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load the page
        return false;
    }
    // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch another Activity that handles URLs
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(intent);
    return true;
}
}
```

To connect WebViewClient with your WebView just set it:

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
```

This link should be usefull https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#HandlingNavigation

***    EDIT      ***

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String uas = "AppleWebKit/537.36" + "(KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/30.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36";
        final WebView view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        view.getSettings().setBlockNetworkLoads(false);
        view.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
        view.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        view.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        view.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
        view.getSettings().setUserAgentString(uas);
        view.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
        view.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        view.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        view.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        view.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        view.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        view.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        view.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

        view.loadUrl("http://58.182.126.214:4567");
    }

    class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("www.example.com")) {
            // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load the page
            return false;
        }
        // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch another Activity that handles URLs
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Could you tell me how do I integrate your piece of code in my code? Thanks. 

Comment: How do i edit this (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("www.example.com")) so that it will open all pages related to my website on the app. For example, www.example.com/help or www.example.com/test. I need it to open **all** pages on that site because the site creates pages all the time. So I need the app to just open all the pages that are located on my site. Please reply quickly. Thanks :) @karol-Żygłowicz

Comment: `Uri.parse(url).getHost()` where `url= "http://www.example.com/help"` or `url="http://www.example.com/test"` will return `"www.example.com"` so instead of www.example.com write your ip or domain (it depends on your link structure) and from that you know if the link is yours or not.

Comment: It doesn't work . It stills prompt me to open up a browser.

Comment: Please help. Thanks